# Tensoring by free modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Show that tensoring by a free module of finite rank preserves arbitrary products

I know that there are some more general statements but I would like to have an explicit proof for this particular case. I tried to use the fact that free modules are flat but without success. In particular I can't see how a possible proof can fail if the rank is not finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\Bigl(\prod_{\lambda}M_\lambda\Bigr)\otimes_R R^n
\cong
\Bigl(\Bigl(\prod_{\lambda}M_\lambda\Bigr)\otimes_R R\Bigr)^{\!n}
\cong
\Bigl(\prod_{\lambda}M_\lambda\Bigr)^{\!n}
\color{red}{\cong}
\Bigl(\prod_{\lambda}M_\lambda^{n}\Bigr)
\cong
\Bigl(\prod_{\lambda}M_\lambda\otimes_R R^{n}\Bigr)
$$

It's a general result that tensoring with *finitely presented* modules commutes with products.

For non finitely generated free modules, the red isomorphism does not hold.

About the red isomorphism (finite case), the map is
$$
\bigl((m^{(k)}_\lambda)_{\lambda}\bigr)_{1\le k\le n}
\mapsto
\bigl((m^{(k)}_\lambda)_{1\le k\le n}\bigr)_{\lambda}
$$
It's a special case of
$$
\prod_{\mu}\Bigl(\prod_{\lambda}M_{\lambda,\mu}\Bigr)
\cong
\prod_{\lambda}\Bigl(\prod_{\mu}M_{\lambda,\mu}\Bigr)
$$

Comment: I don't get why two isomorphisms are true: the red one and the one before it. Could you give me more details please?

Comment: @Blacksmith Tensoring with $R$ is the identity; what's the problem with the red isomorphism? A finite direct sum is the same as a finite product.

Comment: sorry for the first isomorphism, it was trivial. For the red one: don't we need something like that finite sums commute with arbitrary products or like that products commute between them (using your previous comment) ? Both facts seem easy to prove but not so trivial maybe.

Comment: Morever do you have an explicit counterexample for the red isomorphism? I can't see one immediately. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Blacksmith I added some comments. Any nonfinitely generated free module will provide a counterexample, provided the product is of infinitely many nonzero modules.